# How do I transpose the nth row to a column?

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
table columns are:
subject code
date of birth
favorite activities
height (m) 
weight (lbs)
test score + standard deviation 
color blind 
number of siblings
average score

56  6.18  1307  5.73  167  0.564  2  3  1.7  subject_8293748/label/NMA.label

table columns are:
... (repeat)
```

I want to change it to look like this:

```
subject_8293748/label/NMA.label                                 
subject code                      56
date of birth                     6.18
favorite activities               1307
height (m)                        5.73
weight (lbs)                      167
test score + standard deviation   0.564
color blind                       2
number of siblings                3
average score                     1.7

subject..(repeat)
```

How can I do this for every nth row? Thanks so much!

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

How static is your data? Is this cheating?

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ {print $10 "\nsubject code\t\t\t" $1 "\ndate of birth\t\t\t" $2"\nfavorite activities\t\t" $3 "\nheight (m)\t\t\t" $4 "\nweight (lbs)\t\t\t" $5 "\ntest score + standard deviation\t" $6 "\ncolor blind\t\t\t" $7 "\nnumber of siblings\t\t" $8 "\naverage score\t\t\t" $9}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
awk 'BEGIN {
       a[1]="subject code"
       a[2]="date of birth"
       a[3]="favorite activities"
       a[4]="height (m)"
       a[5]="weight (lbs)"
       a[6]="test score + standard deviation"
       a[7]="color blind"
       a[8]="number of siblings"
       a[9]="average score"
     } {
       print $10
       for(c=0;c++<9;) {
         printf "%-34s%s\n",a[c],$c
       }
     }' file.txt
```

**Example run**

```
$ cat file.txt
56  6.18  1307  5.73  167  0.564  2  3  1.7  subject_8293748/label/NMA.label
51  3.18  1307  5.73  167  0.564  2  3  1.7  subject_8293755/label/NMA.label
$ awk 'BEGIN {
       a[1]="subject code"
       a[2]="date of birth"
       a[3]="favorite activities"
       a[4]="height (m)"
       a[5]="weight (lbs)"
       a[6]="test score + standard deviation"
       a[7]="color blind"
       a[8]="number of siblings"
       a[9]="average score"
     } {
       print $10
       for(c=0;c++<9;) {
         printf "%-34s%s\n",a[c],$c
       }
     }' file.txt
subject_8293748/label/NMA.label
subject code                      56
date of birth                     6.18
favorite activities               1307
height (m)                        5.73
weight (lbs)                      167
test score + standard deviation   0.564
color blind                       2
number of siblings                3
average score                     1.7
subject_8293755/label/NMA.label
subject code                      51
date of birth                     3.18
favorite activities               1307
height (m)                        5.73
weight (lbs)                      167
test score + standard deviation   0.564
color blind                       2
number of siblings                3
average score                     1.7
$
```

Comment: Does not work, because not selecting records with proper pattern matching; see my answer below.  (I tried your answer as is, with two attribute blocks following OP's  example data.) Just a heads-up.

Comment: Changing OP's example data... 0_o ?!  Or do you mean to say that the file.txt announced by OP only consists of those attribute-values lines ? Maybe. but not clear to me from OP.  No biggy. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can automate and generalize the treatment of the input file to allow for any attribute names and any number of attribute names, not just the nine showed in OP:

```
   "subject code"
   "date of birth"
   "favorite activities"
   "height (m)"
   "weight (lbs)"
   "test score + standard deviation"
   "color blind"
   "number of siblings"
   "average score"
```

One way of doing so with awk is:

```
awk -v i=0 -v nAtt=9 '
    /table columns are:/ {i+=1;ii=nAtt*(i-1);next} 
    !/(^$|^[0-9]+ +([0-9]+\.*[0-9]+ +)*.+)/ {ii+=1;a[ii]=$0}
    /^[0-9]+ +([0-9]+\.*[0-9]+ +)*.+/ 
        {printf "\n%s\n", $(nAtt+1);
        c=0; 
        for(ii-=nAtt;ii++<1+(nAtt-1)*i;) {c++;printf "%-34s%s\n",a[ii],$c}}
                    ' file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- there are three sections to this awk one-liner, all start with pattern matching, as `/.../`, or anti-matching, as `!/ .../`
- but first when calling `awk`, I pass two external variables with option `-v` to it: `i=0` and `nAtt=9`.  `i` represents the rank of the data block (i.e. the order number of the block of attributes in input file: `file.txt`), while `nAtt` is the number of attributes, which in this solution must be the same for each data block.
- 1st pattern matching: everytime `awk` sees pattern `table columns are:`, it understand that a new data block is starting with the next record, it sets two counters `i` and `ii`, and jumps to the next record.
- 2nd pattern matching: if the record being read is neither a blank line nor a line that could match something like:
  `56  6.18  1307  5.73  167  0.564  2  3  1.7  subject_8293748/label/NMA.label` then increment array `a` 's counter `ii` and start populating the array with attribute name strings, until you reach ...
- 3rd pattern matching: if the record matches `56  6.18  1307  5.73  167  0.564  2  3  1.7` followed by any number of characters, print the `(nAtt+1)`th field in that record, then print the `nAtt` attribute names and values, one of each per line, in such a way that attribute names are left justified and are truncated if longer than 34 characters.

As hinted at before:

- this will work for any number of attributes (nAtt) per attribute block and for attribute names that vary (or not) from block to block.
- a non-constant number of attributes per block is possible (and easy), with minor script modifs.
- external variables can be passed onto `awk`, for instance with:

  `awk -v i=$i -v nAtt=$nAtt '...'`